# If two homotopic maps $f,g: S^n \to Y$ agree on a disk $D$ containing basepoint, then $f,g$ are homotopic rel $D$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have two basepoint-preserving homotopic maps $f\sim g : S^n \to Y$ for some topological space $Y$ which agree on the hemisphere $D \subset S^n$, containing the basepoint. I want to show that they are homotopic by a homotopy that stays fixed on $D$.